# How to tell if you app is using iCloud schema development or production

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa-touch, cloudkit

How can I check at runtime if my iCloud container is connecting to the development or production schema ?

Comment: Its just for debug information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me when running via simulator:

```
    let path = "<pathToProjectDirectory>/<projectName>.entitlements"

    guard let data = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: path) else { return }

    do {
        let dict = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: .mutableContainersAndLeaves, format: nil) as! [String : Any]
        print( "container-environment: \(dict["com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment"] ?? "no key")" )
    }
    catch {
        // error
    }
```